# Test input message text and answer in Django custom admin command

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to test user input confirmation answer in a custom management command. The test is for message displayed to user and answer that she enters.

The commands' code is:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('id', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            experiment = Experiment.objects.get(pk=options['id'])
        except Experiment.DoesNotExist:
            raise CommandError(
                'Experiment with id "%d" does not exist' % (options['id'])
            )

        answer = input('Are you sure? (Y/n)')
        if answer == 'Y':
            experiment.delete()
```

This [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests#21047132) suggests to use mocking, but it's in a lonely context. I want to test the user input as well other things that I could add to the custom command.

What would be an efficient approach?

Answer (score 3):

After searching several sources, I could not find one solution that was similar to my problem. So I mixed some of them to arrive to a neat solution using python `mock` library.

**Test method** (in test_commands.py):

```
from unittest.mock import patch
# other imports

@patch('experiments.management.commands.remove_experiment.get_input',
           return_value='Y')
    def test_remove_experiment_displays_prompt_and_user_confirm_removing(
            self, mock_user_input
    ):
        experiment = create_experiment()
        out = StringIO()
        call_command(
            'remove_experiment', experiment.id, stdout=out
        )

        self.assertEqual(mock_user_input.called, True)
        (text,), kwargs = mock_user_input.call_args
        self.assertEqual(text,
            'All versions of experiment "%s" will be destroyed and cannot be '
            'recovered. Are you sure? (Yes/n) ' % experiment.title)
        self.assertFalse(Experiment.objects.exists())
```

Now, in command Class we wrap python `input()` in our method (like did in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests#21047132) mentioned in the question).

**my_app.management.commands.remove_experiment**:

```
def get_input(text):
    return input(text)

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('id', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            experiment = Experiment.objects.get(pk=options['id'])
        except Experiment.DoesNotExist:
            raise CommandError(
                'Experiment with id "%d" does not exist' % (options['id'])
            )

        answer = get_input('Are you sure? (Y/n)')
        if answer == 'Y':
            experiment.delete()
```

Now, the test will verify the question text, in user input prompt is correct, but will not display it in `stdout`. Besides, the kwarg `return_value='Y'` in `@patch` context decorator will simulate the user answer, and the test passes.