# How to apply mock.patch (unittest) to menu selection function (user-input driven)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function to display a menu for users to input a selection. Based on the user selection, the program then calls separate functions. I am trying to write a test suite for my program and have been unable to pass any tests that would involve user-interaction, so I researched and discovered the Mock() module.

So far, I have been unable to find an example that is close enough to mine to help me in understanding how this would work for user input within a function or a module. I have found useful resources [here](https://medium.com/@yeraydiazdiaz/what-the-mock-cheatsheet-mocking-in-python-6a71db997832) and [here](https://learnbyexample.gitbooks.io/python-basics/content/Testing.html#using-unittest.mock-to-test-user-input-and-program-output) but neither has enabled me to solve my issue. I also checked the forum here to see before asking and while there are topics that are *similar* (e.g. [Python Mocking Raw Input in Unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests)) still with my limited knowledge and the complexity of the task, I am having difficulties taking something I do not understand and applying it in a different way than I am seeing it.

The code I am hoping to test is:

```
import sys

def menu():
    """Display menu of options to toggle between to perform separate actions"""

    selection_dict = {'A': func_A, 'B': func_B, 'C': func_C,
                  'D': func_D, 'E': quit_program, 'Q': quit_program}
    while True:
        selection = input('''
                               -- Menu Options --

                           A. Call Function A
                           B. Call Function B
                           C. Call Function C
                           D. Call Function D
                           E. Quit

                           Menu Selection: ''').upper()
        print()
        try:                         
            selection_dict[selection]()
        except ValueError:
            print('Incorrect entry. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.')

def func_A():
    print('Function a')
    menu()

def func_B():
    print('Function b')
    menu()

def func_C():
    print('Function c')
    menu()

def func_D():
    print('Function d')
    menu()

def func_E():
    print('Function e')
    menu()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu()  # Program starts here
```

The test that I have tried so far (that fails) is:

```
from unittest import mock
from io import StringIO
import my_file as m


class Test_file(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
    def test_mock(self, tst_str, mock_stdout):
        with mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=tst_str):
            m.menu()
        return mock_stdout.getvalue()

    def test_entry(self):
       self.assertEqual(self.test_mock(), 'Menu Options?')  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The code you showed won't run at all. Can you create a [mcve] and add it to the question along with the error you get?

Comment: I have updated the code to show the basic idea of what the menu is doing (the program is large and I have been chewed out on here before for providing _too_ much code. In reference to the unittest code, however, it is correct that it does not run as I am having difficulty in applying/understanding this concept. I was hoping that someone might be able to explain how it works (not do my work for me).

Comment: What is the purpose of `tst_str`? Do you want to write a test and then run it multiple times for different inputs?