# Handling inputs in unittest, test begins but nothing else happens

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I need to test a function that handles inputs. I'm a newbie in all about unittests and mocks so I just basically followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047132/6531256 that it looks very similar to my case.
Well, the problem is that when i run the test it seems to start but just stay there and nothing happens. I need to quit with ctrl-c to stop it, then I get a traceback that not helps very much(at least for me).

Here is the test code:

```py
import unittest
import unittest.mock
from unittest.mock import patch
from work1 import User

class TestWork1(unittest.TestCase, User):

    @patch('builtins.input', return_value= "36")
    def test_userNum(self,return_value):

        self.assertEqual(self.userNum(), "Invalid number. Put a 4-digit number:")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Here the function trying to test:

```py
class User():

    def userNum(self):

        self.user_num = int(input("Put a 4-digit number"))
        while len(str(self.user_num)) != 4:
            self.user_num = int(input("Invalid number. Put a 4-digit number:"))
```

Here is an example of a Traceback (always are a little diferent):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 255, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 648, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 600, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1157, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/cristian/venvs/EB/test_work1.py", line 15, in test_userNum
    self.assertEqual(self.userNum(), "Invalid number. Put a 4-digit number:")
  File "/home/cristian/venvs/EB/work1.py", line 15, in userNum
    self.user_num = int(input("Invalid number. Put a 4-digit number:""))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 916, in __call__
    _mock_self._mock_check_sig(*args, **kwargs)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

1. Your loop runs infinitely because you patch `builtin.input` to always return `"36"`.  This will not allow the loop to exit - when you run the code, it seems that nothing happens, but the code is just looping.  To see what happens, you can put `print()` statements at the interesting places.  To fix it, you either have to define `return_value` such that it returns a 4-digit number, or you have to define `side_effect` to be a list like `["36", "1234"]` such that consecutive calls to `builtin.input` return different values.  The latter option is shown in the code example below.
2. Your assertion compares the result of `self.userNum()` against a string.  But, `self.userNum()` does not return anything.  From your test code it seems you want to test that `buitin.input` was called with the respective argument string.  How this can be done is shown in the code below - as one possible solution, where in fact the whole sequence of calls to `builtin.input` is checked.  This is only for demonstration, not to imply that it should be done this way.

Possible solution:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock
from unittest.mock import patch, call

class User():
    def userNum(self):
        self.user_num = int(input("Put a 4-digit number"))
        while len(str(self.user_num)) != 4:
            self.user_num = int(input("Invalid number. Put a 4-digit number:"))

class TestWork1(unittest.TestCase, User):
    @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["36", "1234"])
    def test_userNum(self, input_mock):
        expected = [
            call('Put a 4-digit number'),
            call('Invalid number. Put a 4-digit number:')]
        self.userNum()
        self.assertEqual(input_mock.mock_calls, expected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Sir your answer is right. I was stuck there and had to solve it to finish the task. Find this by myself sure it will have been hard for me.. I would like to sincerely thank Mr. Dirk.