# How to pass a value to interactive input in a passive way in Python?

Tags: python, input

I use a function that gets some input from the user interactively and returns some values. I'd like to run the function (**without changing it**) without having to type in the values myself, e.g. have it read from a list. How can I achieve this?

MCVE:

```py
def add():
    a = int(input('first number: '))
    b = int(input('first number: '))
    return(a+b)
```

And I want to be able to run something like `magic(add(), [2, 3])` to get the output `5`.

Comment: You should write your function to take a list as argument.

Comment: I think it is only possible if you run another program that inputs some data.

Comment: You can use a batch or shell script to send data to a program

Comment: Can you add some more context on why you need to do this? It seems like a pattern to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are on Linux or wsl, you can just pipe some input through stdin. I.e.,

```
$ echo $'1\n3\n' | python scripy.py
```

should produce 4. If you have a file with the same contents, you can do the same using `cat`

```
$ cat file.in | python script.py
```

*only if absolutely necessary*:

python can also be used to simulate stdin. sys.stdin is simply an instance of the StringIO class. We can override the default sys.stdin with a StringIO class with contents of our choice.

```
with StringIO(in_string) as f:
    tmp = sys.stdin
    sys.stdin = f
    add()
    sys.stdin = tmp
```

Comment: That's helpful, but I really need to do it within my python code.

Comment: the StringIO still asks for input

Comment: @kmi see example https://repl.it/repls/GlassCloudyPiracy#main.py

Comment: I see. It seems like the environment makes a difference. Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make a test where you mock out `input`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("builtins.input")
def test_add(mock_input):
    input_values = [2, 3]
    mock_input.side_effect = input_values
    expected_value = sum(input_values)
    actual_value = add()
    # print or log actual value here if you want to see the result
    assert actual_value == expected_value
```

this is quite a round about way if you are trying to automate the use of some third party function that annoyingly uses `input`, but if you're just trying to test their function, its not bad.

Comment: This is very close to what I need but it complains on the `@patch` line: `Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'input'`

Comment: Use “builtins.input”, that will patch what you want. It might be “builtin.input”. I can never remember.

Comment: Hmmm, try `@patch("builtins.input")` instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37449365/1011724 note btw the easiest way to run this test is via pytest

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That did the trick. This works perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

If you have your values in a list of any size, then `sum` will work.

```
def add(A):
    return sum(A)
```