# How can you monkeypatch an input call from a nested function?

Tags: python, pytest, stdin

I am a novice python coder on my greatest of days.  I am in a class and using pytest to wrap my head around TDD.  Some of the functions in this code (based off of Dane Hillard's Bark) calls a function that prompts the user for input.  I need to automate the input of the nested function.

```
def get_user_input(label, required=True):
    value = input(f"{label}: ") or None
    while required and not value:
        value = input(f"{label}: ") or None
    return value

def get_new_bookmark_data():
    return {
        "title": get_user_input("Title"),
        "url": get_user_input("URL"),
        "notes": get_user_input("Notes", required=False),
    }
```

I can't even wrap my head around how I should deal with test_get_user_input() much less the bookmark.

Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
def test_get_user_input(monkeypatch):
    uInput = 'a'
    monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', uInput)
    assert barky.get_user_input() == 'A'
```

I'm just not there yet.  Here is my repo: https://github.com/impilcature/Green-CIDM6330

Comment: I'd focus on testing the **logic** of getting the user input (ie how `value` and `required` interact) rather than testing `input` itself, since at that point you'd be testing Python's built-in functions.

Comment: @DeepSpace Isn't that just get_new_bookmark_data() calls get_user_input() and passes "Title" to it.  The Title is then passed to input which displays the line to the user who then enters the title name which is returned to get_new_bookmark_data() and then it cycles to the next get_user_input call ... ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python mocking raw input in unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests). Note the answer for Python 3 (the accepted answer is for Python 2).

Comment: No, it doesn’t. I’m using pytest not unittest. Specifically, my hurdle is that a method calls a method that then calls for user input.

Comment: I'll clarify in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is done the same way in pytest as in unittest by using `unittest.mock.patch`, in your case by mocking the `input` function that lives in `buildins`. So you can just do:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("builtins.input")
def test_get_user_input(mocked):
    mocked.return_value = "a"
    assert get_user_input('foo') == 'a'
```

That mocks `input` regardless of where it is called, so it doesn't matter if you call it in the tested function or in a function called by the tested function.

To be more consistent with the pytest way, you can install the pytest plugin [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) which provides the `mocker` fixture, which is a wrapper around `unittest.mock`:

```py
def test_get_user_input(mocker):
    mocker.patch('builtins.input', return_value='a')
    assert get_user_input('foo') == 'a'
```

If you want to test more than one input, you can use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=side_effect#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to provide subsequent inputs (here using the `mocker` fixture):

```py
def test_get_new_bookmark_data(mocker):
    mocker.patch('builtins.input',
                 side_effect=["Some title", "Some URL", "Some notes"])
    assert get_new_bookmark_data() == {
        "title": "Some title",
        "url": "Some URL",
        "notes": "Some notes"
    }
```