# How to write unit test functions with two input functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing

The difficulty lies in the fact that the function has 2 input functions.

```
name_of_numbers = {1: 'Первый', 2: 'Второй', 3: 'Третий', 4: 'Червертый', 5: 'Пятый', 6: 'Шестой', 7: 'Седьмой', 8: 'Восьмой', 9: 'Девятый', 10: 'Десятый', 11: 'Одиннадцатый', 12: 'Двенадцатый', 13: 'Тринадцатый', 14: 'Четырнадцатый', 15: 'Пятнадцатый', 16: 'Шестнадцатый', 17: 'Семнадцатый', 18: 'Восемнадцатый', 19: 'Девятнадцатый'}
```

```
def get_dictionary() -> dict:
    database = dict()
    amount_of_orders = int(input('Количество заказов: '))
    for number in range(1, amount_of_orders + 1):
        customer, pizza_name, count = input(f'{name_of_numbers[number]} заказ: ').split()
        if customer in database:
            if pizza_name in database[customer]:
                database[customer][pizza_name] += int(count)
            else:
                database[customer][pizza_name] = count
        else:
            database[customer] = dict({pizza_name: int(count)})
    return database
```

Comment: what unit testing package are you using?

Comment: Unittest unit testing package.

Forgot to specify the input data

# Иванов Пепперони 1
# Петров Де-Люкс 2
# Иванов Мясная 3
# Иванов Мексиканская 2
# Иванов Пепперони 2
# Петров Интересная 5

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing this one would be simple. You only need to understand (1) how to mock the `input()` function, and (2) how to mock it multiple times with different outputs.

For #1:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047132/2307345) has a clue on how to handle mocking `input`

so in your code, you might want to wrap the `input()` into a wrapper function `get_input` like:

```
def get_input(text):
     return input(text)
```

and replace your `input()` functions with `get_input()`

```
amount_of_orders = int(get_input('Количество заказов: '))
...
get_input(f'{name_of_numbers[number]} заказ: ').split()
```

For #2: You might want to use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide). this feature allows you to have multiple return values of a mock depending on the array of values you provided in it.

As for how the unit test would probably look, this would be a good example:

```
@patch('yourmodule.get_input', side_effect=['input1', 'input2'])
def test_get_dictionary():
    result = get_dictionary()
    # assertions here
```